# Fire event from ManWindow in selected tab

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tabcontrol, code-behind

I'm sorry if this question was asked before.
After 1 hour of searching here i could not to find it.

First, i'm using WPF, but not with MVVM. I know MVVM is way to go and i'm learning it. I'm new to programming.

It's small program and i have buttons on mainwindow in one StackPanel, and TabControl (_tabcntrl) in another.

On button click mainwindow generates one tab:

```
TabItem _tab = new TabItem();
UserControl _uc = new UserControl();
_tab.Content = _uc;
_tabcntrl.Items.Add(tab);
```

In usercontrol i have one public event

```
public void test()
{
   //some code
}
```

So my question is how to fire this event from main window (button click in main window), but only in selected tab. Idea is that you can have multiple tabs with same usercontrol.

I know i can do it with

```
_uc.test();
```

But only when tab is created.

Also i tried to put

```
    TabItem tb = _tabcntrl.SelectedItem;
    tb.test();
```

In button click event, but i get error.

Stupid thing is that i figured out how to fire event from usercontrol, and i can't other way around. Feeling pretty stupid for asking this in first place.

Thank You, sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options, you can either look for `VisualTree` or simply use `Children` property of the `Control` and find respective element.

```
TabItem tb = _tabcntrl.SelectedItem;
var childControls = control.Children.OfType<UserControl>(); // your controltype

// I'm looping through all child controls of type 'UserControl' but you can customize to your case.

foreach(var control in childControls)
{
     // execute control logic here
     control.test();
}
```

Comment: Thx for VisualTree and Children property.

I found easy way with only two lines of code for selecteditem only

// Game_settings is name of UserControl

var ctrl = _tabcntrl.SelectedContent as Game_settings; 
ctrl.test();

Comment: Great, but please mind your solution only works when there is _only_ UserControl in the tab, this might fail when you have multiple controls or hierarchy of items inside .

Comment: In this case, it will be. But thx for heads up, I'm gonna keep that in mind.